# Measuring orbital angular momentum in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics

How do we measure orbital angular momentum of electron experimentally? I know if we consider spin then we can calculate value of orbital angular mome tum indirectly by Stern Gerlach experiment.But is there a way to calculate 'l' directly? 
And what is meaning of zero orbital angular momentum for ground state of hydrogen atom? Does it implies :

1. electron is not rotating? Or
   2.At a non zero distance from origin?or
2. We measure average of angular momentum as wavefunction is spherically symmetric?

Comment: Historically, the notion of orbital angular momentum was a consequence of experiments done by Zeeman. http://www.pas.rochester.edu/~blackman/ast104/zeeman-split.html

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski what is the reason that energy levels for ground state H atom will Not split in magnetic field? I know because l=0. But question Is what is meaning of l=0!?